# MongoDB data directory confusion

Tags: mongodb, database-connection

I want to use MongoDB Compass on Windows 7 to manage my data, but I cannot figure out how to change the data directory.

I have used the command 
`mongod --dbpath="C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\test"`

But when I use Compass to add a new database or a collection, nothing appears in "test" folder. Instead, I got new files added in "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\data", which I believe is the default directory?
I think the command is not successfully executed but I don't know what to do.[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSYx4.png)

I have also tried to modify the mongodb.cfg which is located in "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin". But it does not work either.

Can anyone help please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the file permission on your folder.

MongoD reports that clearly. See the image below.

MongoD is unable to create lock file on read-only directory.

The lock file is some kind of guarantee that the other MongoD instance can not run on the same directory.

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's why I thought the command was not executed successfully. So how can I solve it? All folders I create are read-only and I cannot get rid of that attribute. I have searched online of how to remove the read-only attribute, but none of them seems to work.